# How can the FieldOffsetAttribute in c# be compatible with the garbage collector if you can have two fields at the same location?

Tags: c#, struct, garbage-collection, unions, unsafe

In C# you can do this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public class Stuff
{
    public int blah1 = 3;
    public String blah2 = "sadfsadf";
    public bool blah3 = true;
    public ulong blah4 = 23423423420569032;
    public Stuff next;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct SYSTEM_INFO
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public String Blah1;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int[] Blah2;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Stuff Blah3;
}
```

I don't understand how the garbage collection, when moving objects in the managed heap and changing where the pointers refer to will be able to do this without radically changing the behaviour of this and how it will be able to walk the stack.

If the garbage collectors moves a string located in `Blah1`, in will try to change the reference at `Blah1`, which will indirectly change the references at `Blah2` and `Blah3`. Will this mean the garbage collector will then automatically collect the referred objects at `Blah2` and `Blah3`, had they been only referred in this `SYSTEM_INFO` struct?

How will the garbage collector know whether the `Blah3` field is a valid Stuff, which should be walked to know whether the next fields need to marked as used, or whether the `Blah3` field is just pointing to the start of a string (used from `Blah1`)?

Comment: It will look at the type of the object the reference points to, not at the type of the field referring to it. It would have to do that anyway because of inheritance.

Comment: Now, that is not to say that your type is completely bogus, as you can't have 1 reference that is both a string and an int array and some other class. I find it odd that the compiler doesn't detect this, but for GC, it's not really a problem.

Comment: For reference, you can get into some *seriously* odd scenarios by overlapping references like this - essentially you can break how virtual-call works, and end up calling methods on the wrong instance type. My advice: **never do this**. However, it isn't a problem for the GC. The GC just walks the reference to the next `object` - the `object` knows what itself is. Overlapping value-types that don't involve references: absolutely fine, no problem. Ish.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the inheritance point clears alot of things up. How does the GC know whether something is an object/reference or a valuetype? Surely when it looks at the stack, it just sees int64 (on x64) -> a valid address is also a valid long no?

Comment: Yes, but there is a header before the reference address for each object that the GC can use to determine the type pointed to (see [Managed object internals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/)).

Comment: It knows the type of the struct you're in, so it will know that at that location in the struct, there will be a reference to an object, not just 4/8 random bytes making a number or whatever. And then when it follows that reference it will find, as @NetMage says, a few fields with information about the type of object in that location as well, and use that information to know how big the object is and what's in each byte.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen As pointed out in the original question, it is possible to have field offets overlap, (.e.g like a C union) in which case the same bytes could either be a number or be a reference to an object, determined by the program at runtime. Without some outside marker on the pointed to destination, it is impossible for the GC to know which `struct` member is valid at any given time.

Comment: Please show such an example as I am unable to get that to run, you get a ReflectionTypeLoadException with "Could not load type 'SYSTEM_INFO' from assembly 'xyz' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.", and that is without any code at all that deals with the type, just the declaration is enough.

Comment: The example in the question contains 3 object references in the same position. This will cause some odd results at runtime, but GC will be able to cope. But make one of the fields a number or something else and you get that exception. So as far as I know, no, that is not possible.

Comment: @NetMage Lasse's theory makes more sense, since it explains why you're not allowed to overlap value types and reference types, presumably for this reason where you can't tell!

Comment: I see, I didn't pay attention to your union not actually having value fields...

Comment: Does one of you want to write up your comment as an answer? I'll happily accept it